# unable to redirect from servlet to jsp page

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to create a small registeration form using jsp and servlet.
The concept goes like this:
The data being enterd in the jsp form will be checked for duplication by a servlet program.
If duplication exists , then the control must return back to the registeration (jsp) page from where the servlet was called.
I am doing this in eclipse helios.
Servlet program is under the default package under java resources ,
and jsp file is under the web content folder.

My problem is that
I am able to redirect from jsp to servlet;

but when I try to return back to the jsp page from the servlet ,
 tomcat server is showing error like:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /RservletEs/registeration.jsp

type Status report

message /RservletEs/reg.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.
```

I tried both request.dispatcher() and response.sendRedirect() both are showing same error.

The file path is:

```
RservletEs/src/ServletCheck
Rservlets/Web Content/registeration.jsp
```

I have attached the source code below 
somebody pls help me out of this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHitField;
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchType;

import java.util.Map;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletCheck
*/
@WebServlet("/ServletCheck")
public class ServletCheck extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
  * /
 public ServletCheck() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String clusterName="asdf";
    String hostName="localcost";
    String index="testdb";
    String type="emp_type";
    String field="emailId";
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();



    int portNumber=26101;

    final TransportClient client = new TransportClient(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", clusterName)
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build());

    Settings settings = client.settings();

    out.println("**settings:"+ settings);

    ImmutableMap<String, String> map = settings.getAsMap();

    out.println("**map::"+ map);

    ((TransportClient) client).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(hostName, portNumber));

    out.println("ES client:" + client);
    String firstName=request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName=request.getParameter("lastName");
    String emailId=request.getParameter("emailId");
    String age=request.getParameter("age");
    String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
    String eId=request.getParameter("employeeId");

    String value=emailId;


    SearchResponse response2 = client.prepareSearch(index)
   .setTypes(type)
   .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
   .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery(field, value))
   .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true).setRouting("1")
   .execute()
   .actionGet();

    SearchHit[] results = response2.getHits().getHits();
    int length=results.length;
    int i=0;

    if (length>0){
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/registeration.jsp");
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("/registeration.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else{

            out.println("setting the values");

            hr_employee tweet = new hr_employee();

            out.println("setting the id");

            tweet.setEmployeeId(eId);

            tweet.setFirstName(firstName);
            out.println("setting the last name");
            tweet.setLastName(lastName);
            tweet.setEmailId(emailId);
            tweet.setDob(dob);



            String str=tweet.getEmployeeId();
           /* System.out.println("the id is...."+str);
            System.out.println("the firstname .... "+tweet.getFirstName());
            System.out.println("teh last name....."+tweet.getLastName());
           */

        out.println("initiallizing req builder");           
        final IndexRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareIndex(index, type,str);

        out.println("setting source");
        builder.setSource(new Gson().toJson(tweet));
        out.println("getting response");
        final IndexResponse response3 = builder.setRouting("1").execute().actionGet();

         out.println("geting connected...");

        out.println("ElasticSearchEJBBean:indexDocument:" + index+ ":" + type+ ":" + str + ":index results:" + response3);
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/ServletInsert");
        }






    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub



      doGet(request,response);



    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like there must be some problem with the way u name it.
Try like this:

```
right click on ur jsp file and select copy qualified name .
```

then use that name to redirect or dispatch like this:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/registeration .jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since jsp is under the `web-content` folder do this

```
response.sendRedirect("/registeration.jsp");
```

or try something like this

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/registeration.jsp"));
```